# laravel images validation not work

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have craeted validation on images but its not working and back to page and input are empty
any error in code ?

```
    $this->validate($request, [
         'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif',
    ]); 
    $ADS = new ADS; 
    $ADS->title = Input::get('title');
    $ADS->detals = Input::get('detals');
    $ADS->city = Input::get('city');
    $ADS->country = Input::get('country');
    $ADS->id_user = Auth::user()->id;
    $ADS->type= Input::get('type'); 
    $ADS->years= Input::get('years'); 
    $ADS->save(); 

    if(Input::hasFile('image')){
        foreach ($request->file('image') as $file){
            $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $picture = date('His').$name;
            $myimg = $file->move('uploads',$picture);
            $Photos = new Photos; 
            $Photos->id_ads = $ADS->id;
            $Photos->type = 1;  
            $Photos->photo = $myimg;            
            $Photos->save();                 
        }    
    }
```

Comment: What issue is coming validating image?

Comment: did you check your request body?

Comment: Are you uploading multiple images?

Comment: yes i uploading multiple images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank u for all
i slolved it by add

```
        if(Input::hasFile('image')){
        $this->validate($request, [
             'image.*' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif',
        ],['image.*' => 'الملف يجب  ان يكون من نوع صورة']);             
        foreach ($request->file('image') as $file){
            $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $picture = date('His').$name;
            $myimg = $file->move('uploads',$picture);
            $Photos = new Photos; 
            $Photos->id_ads = $ADS->id;
            $Photos->type = 1;  
            $Photos->photo = $myimg;            
            $Photos->save();                 
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If inputs are empty try `$request->all();` check if this command returns your form value or not. If you'll be able to see the form result then you can continue else you have to check whether your action url in the form is correct or not.

And for file uploading do not forget to put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form's opening tag.

Instead of using `Input::get('title')` why don't you use `$request->get('title')` a bit more cleaner way isn't it?

Well you don't have to use image in your validation, `mimes` will be ok:

do change your below code of yours:

```
$this->validate($request, [
         'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif',
    ]);
```

into this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
         'image' => ''mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif',
    ]);
```

This should work for you, for more infomration please visit this url https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-mimetypes the official documentation regarding laravel mime types validation.

Happy Coding!

Comment: when i use 
        $this->validate($request, [
                 'image' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif',
            ]); 
it'back to add page with error
The image must be a file of type: jpeg, jpg, png, gif.
and i select png image !!!

Comment: Did you use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form?